# having two gmail accounts, some contacts are in both accounts, which name is displayed?

Tags: contacts, gmail, whatsapp-messenger

I have two gmail accounts, personal, and work.

some contacts are in both accounts, but I can't choose how are they displayed in incoming calls and whatsapp.

my work account is controlled by my boss, and has weird names, but it's the account that actually names everything.

I'm not syncing the contacts, and they are hided, but still there in whatsapp and calls.